# Que día de la semana fue esa fecha

Tags: javascript

se tiene que dar la fecha para que me de el día de la semana, pero me da fechas erróneas cuando es año bisiesto
Necesito que salga correctamente el día
por ejemplo: pongo 10/1/2002 y me da Miércoles y en verdad fue Jueves

```
     function gregoriano(D,M,Y){
        let fecha = D + "/" + M + "/" + Y;
        let h, K, J, a, b, c;
        if(Y%2 == 0 || Y/400 == 0 ){
            if (M <= 2) {
                a = M + 10 ;
                b = (Y - 1) % 100;
                c = Math.floor((Y - 1) / 100);
            } else if (M >= 3) {
                a = M - 2;
                b = Y % 100;
                c = Math.floor(Y / 100);
            }
            h = Math.floor((700 + ((26*a-2)/10) + D + b + (b/4) + ((c/4) - (2*c) - 1))%7);
        }else{
            if(M<=2){
                M = M + 12;
                Y = Y - 1;
            }else{
                M = M - 2;
            }
            K = Y % 100;
            J = Math.floor(Y / 100);

            h = parseInt((700 + Math.floor((26 * M - 2) / 10) + D + K + Math.floor(K/4) + Math.floor((J/4) + 5 * J)) % 7);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

No es necesario hacer nada de eso. Aprovecha las funciones de [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

En este caso fíjate que a tu función le resto 1 al mes, puesto que los meses trabajan del 0 al 11.

Si quisieras el número que indica el día de la semana solamente usa la función `date.getDay`, la cual te devuelve un número entre 0 y 6 indicando el día de la semana.

```js
function gregoriano(D, M, Y) {
  return new Date(Y, M - 1, D).toLocaleDateString("es-MX", {  weekday: 'long' });
}

const date = new Date();
console.log(gregoriano(10, 1, 2002));
console.log(gregoriano(03, 5, 2010));
console.log(gregoriano(date.getDate(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getFullYear()));
```